# Random coefficients and fixed effects

Tags: mathematical-statistics, mixed-model, estimation, regression-coefficients, fixed-effects-model

In a nonlinear model, for each time $t\in\{1,..,T\}$ and product $ j\in \{1,..,J_t\} $ individual $i \in \{1,...,I_{t}\} $ chooses an amount $y_{i,j,t}$ modeled as

$ q_{i,j,t} = \frac{1}{\tau_j k_{j,t}} exp \{X_{j,t}^T (\beta+\beta_i)  + \sum_r z_{i,r}X_{j,t}^T\gamma^{(r)} + \zeta_{j,t}\}$

where $ \beta_i \thicksim \mathcal N(\mathbb 0_K , D), D=diag(\sigma_k)_{k=1}^K $ represents the random coefficients, and $\zeta_{j,t}$ are some un-observable factors for which we have bunch of instruments. Each individual has $R$ observable characteristics $(z_{i,r})_{r=1}^R$ and the vector of parameters to estimate is $\theta=(\beta,\gamma^{(1)},\gamma^{(2)},...,\gamma^{(R)},\sigma_1,\sigma_2,...\sigma_K)$. Finally, $\tau_j$ and $k_{j,t}$ are some observables included also as part of $X_{j,t}$. Please note that each individual $i$ only chooses one product $j_{i,t}$ at each time so we can observe only $ q_{i,j_{i,t},t} $ in our data. I have the following estimation strategy in mind and I want to see if it will give me consistent estimates and whether or not it is over-kill.

First I transform the model by defining  $ y_{i,j,t} = \ln q_{i,j,t} + \ln \tau_j + \ln k_{j,t} $ then I have

$\\ y_{i,j,t} = X_{j,t}^T (\beta+\beta_i)  + \sum_r z_{i,r}X_{j,t}^T\gamma^{(r)} + \zeta_{j,t}$.

Normally we cannot identify $\zeta_{j,t}$ separately using product-time fixed effects but since I know by  construction, $\mathbb E[\zeta.X] = 0 $, I thought I might be able to identify them in a 2-stage estimation process (similar to mixed-logit models):

I - Define $\delta_{j,t} = X_{j,t}^T \beta+ \zeta_{j,t} $ and fit a model to get estimates for $ ((\gamma_r)_{r=1}^R,(\sigma_k)_{k=1}^K,(\delta)_{j,t}) $.

II - Estimate the $\beta$ as in $\hat\beta=(XX^T)^{-1}X\hat\delta$ using the estimated  $\hat\delta$ in a regression across product-times.

Specifically, I am asking the following questions:

1- Do I get consistent estimates this way?

2- Is there a more straightforward way of getting what I want, given the nonlinearity with respect to $((\gamma_r)_{r=1}^R,(\sigma_k)_{k=1}^K)$

3- Is it at all legit to bring the two observables $\tau $ and $ k_{j,t} $ that show up also on the right-hand-side covariates i.e. $X$ to the left-hand-side for the second (linear) regression stage?